# launching selenium tests without using maven test command

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, selenium

In a web page ,i  want to create a button so when i click on it , maven launch the already written selenium tests .
So have you any idea : it is possible or not ?

Comment: Hm. you wan't to start tests don't want to do mvn test ? Did i understand that correct?

Comment: Why do you want to run selenium through Maven? Are you creating some sort of Continuous Integration tool? Although you can call specific plugin's specific goal, I am not sure if you really need maven to do this, specially since you need to do this from a Web Application.

Comment: yes this is what i meant :)) @Kal i used maven to launch tests so is there another solution tu launch them automatically

Comment: @AmiraManai I think all you need then is to simply use JUnit API to directly call the test runner and collect results. You would have to make sure that all the classpath dependencies etc are set appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing is to write the selenium tests as real integration tests put them into an appropriate module or name them based on integration tests (see maven-failsafe-plugin) furthermore put the configuration for the maven-failsafe-plugin into a profile which makes it possible to turn on/off the integration tests with selenium. But not to use the mvn test Hm..best thing is to use integration-test lifycylce with pre-integration-test, integration-test and post-integration-test which is followed by the verify lifecycle phase which usually can be used for such purposes.